# Cassandra 4.5 driver issue with @Entity and Counter fields

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-driver

Having a problem with the 4.5 Datastax Cassandra driver.  I cannot get any of these @Queries to work:

```
@Dao
public interface SampleTable2Dao extends BaseDao<SampleTable2> {
    //@Query("UPDATE sampletable2 SET cntrfld = cntrfld + :toAdd WHERE key1 = :key1Value AND key2 = :key2Value AND key3 = :key3Value")
    @Query("UPDATE sampletable2 SET cntrfld = cntrfld + 1 WHERE key1 = 1 AND key2 = 1 AND key3 = 1;")
    CompletableFuture<Void> addCountAsync(int toAdd, int key1Value, int key2Value, int key3Value);

    @Query("UPDATE sampletable2 SET cntrfld = cntrfld + 1 WHERE key1 = 1 AND key2 = 1 AND key3 = 1;")
    void addCount(int toAdd, int key1Value, int key2Value, int key3Value);

    @Query("UPDATE sampletable2 SET cntrfld = cntrfld + 1 WHERE key1 = 1 AND key2 = 1 AND key3 = 1;")
    void addCount();
```

It simply hangs:
`getSampleTable2Dao().addCount();`

The queries work fine directly in Cassandra.

Thanks

P.S. here is the table for anyone wants to test:

```
CREATE TABLE sampletable2 (
    key1 int,
    key2 int,
    key3 int,
    cntrfld counter,
    PRIMARY KEY (key1, key2, key3)
);
```

update #1

After some digging, I find that it's in this generated code where it's hanging.  Nothing to do with the actual query:

```
this.sampleTable2DaoCache = new LazyReference<>(() -> SampleTable2DaoImpl__MapperGenerated.init(context));

  @Override
  public SampleTable2Dao sampleTable2Dao() {
    return sampleTable2DaoCache.get();
  }
```

I'm working my way backwards stripping things out until I can get it working.  Other DAOs work fine - the only difference with this is the counter field.

UPDATE #2... the "real" issue, is not @Query at all... but @Entity with counter fields.

```
@CqlName("cntrfld")
private Long cntrFld;
```

If this field is a counter in Cassandra (3.11.4 btw) the code just hangs.  If I make the field a bigint, it works just fine!

Comment: It works for me. How are you building your session? One potential issue is that there is no keyspace in the query string, so your session needs to have a default one (`CqlSession.builder().withKeyspace(...)`). But still a missing keyspace should produce an error, not hang.

Comment: That's not the issue... I cannot get it to connect without the keyspace... and it can connect.  I have another dao working just fine.

Comment: I tried 4.5.1, and it is still broken.  I'm at a stand-still... Seems i cannot use a counter field with mappers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to use `@Insert` or `@Update` with a counter column. That won't work: [counters](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11.3/cql/types.html#counters) are a special type of column, they only support increment or decrement operations.

You can use an entity for read or delete operations though. But for updates, `@Query` is your only option right now:

```
@Entity @CqlName("sampletable2")
public class SampleTable2 {
  @PartitionKey private int key1;
  @ClusteringColumn(1) private int key2;
  @ClusteringColumn(2) private int key3;
  private long cntrfld;
  // getters and setters...
}

@Dao
public interface SampleTable2Dao {
  @Select
  SampleTable2 get(int key1, int key2, int key3);

  @Delete
  void delete(SampleTable2 entity);

  @Query(
      "UPDATE sampletable2 SET cntrfld = cntrfld + 1 "
          + "WHERE key1 = :key1 AND key2 = :key2 AND key3 = :key3")
  void increment(int key1, int key2, int key3);

  // THIS WON'T WORK:
  // @Insert
  // void insert(SampleTable2 entity);
}
```

Admittedly, we could have better support for counters in the mapper. I think something like this could work:

```
  @Increment
  void increment(SampleTable2 entity);
```

I've created [JAVA-2721](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-2721) to explore the idea.

Comment: Actually... my BaseDao<T> does have an Insert... maybe that's it.  I'll try to remove it.  It should throw an error though, not just hang forever.  just a thought.  ;)

Comment: I like the idea of an @ Increment.  BUT, you need to be able to control the number to increment.  I.E. @ Increment void increment(SampleTable2 entity, long delta);  Or, would you have the code put the delta number in the entity variable field before calling?

Comment: Yes, we'll have to refine the API a little bit: different increments (including negative), multiple counters, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The error was, my @Dao had an @Insert, but the table used a counter field type.  Once I removed the @Insert, then the system worked.

I followed the help and created a BaseDao< T > class that contained repetitive @Insert and @Delete sets of methods, so it wasn't obvious what I had wrong.

The library SHOULD throw an error in this situation, and not just hang...  that's a bug int he library I think.

Comment: I am getting an error by the way: `com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: INSERT statements are not allowed on counter tables, use UPDATE instead` when I get the DAO from the mapper. There might be something else going on, try debugging maybe.